# Use Vuforia iOS SDK in a Swift project for an augmented reality app

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to integrate the Vuforia iOS SDK in order to try marker-tracking for an augmented reality app **in Swift**.

At first I wanted to run one of their samples but I canot get it to compile (I'm unsure of the required steps, maybe I'm missing bridging headers, compilation flags etc.).

Here is what I've done and tried so far :

- Created a new Swift project
- Downloaded the iOS SDK [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk?d=windows-30-16-4114)
- Downloaded the iOS samples [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples)
- Drag and dropped the iOS SDK in the root folder of the Xcode project

As this point, everything is fine, it compiles. Then I add the samples by drag and dropping in the samples folder and tried to Build. It shows about Vuforia imports so I guess it's not correctly added to the project.

Have I missed one or many steps ? Do I have to manually create a bridging header ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm also struggling with this for 2 days now... But I got the samples to run at least. You don't need to drop them into your project (you shouldn't). Run them on their own. Just remember to add your license key...

Comment: How do you solve it? Because "VuforiaSampleSwift" not compile now with 8.+ vuforia sdk version. Vuforia not provide official documentation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to manually create bridging headers for Swift, because Vuforia currently only has C++, Java and Unity APIs. This [project](https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift) is an example of the final result.

Hope it helps someone,
Xavi

Comment: Please do not simply throw links at the OP. It is considered more helpful if you explain in your answer why the links helps answering. This prevents the info getting lost in case the linked document is moved.